# Meteor - Making DOM Changes from Helpers

Tags: meteor

Is it a good practice to make DOM changes from Meteor helpers? I'm currently relying on a javascript function to run inside the Meteor helper which makes the function run every time a collection data change occurs.

I know there is Tracker.autorun() but as far as I know, Tracker.autorun() only works for Session variables and does not work for collection data changes.

My current ways so far has not failed me or caused any problems but I'm not 100% sure if this was how Meteor was meant to be used.

Code Example

```
Template.page_body.helpers({
    orange: function() {
        do_some_rand_function()
        return this.name
    }
})
```

This code will make sure that do_some_rand_function() is ran every time this.name changes (this.name is a variable gotten from a Mongo Collection, therefore it is reactive).

Comment: Pieces of code would help understand your question! You might want to check what is a reactive variable, what is Session and what are cursors too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Helpers should not have side effects (such as manually updating your DOM, modifying the database, making an HTTP request, etc.).

Your description sounds like a good use case for adding a [template autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun) in the rendered callback. All autoruns are reactive computations so they will rerun if any reactive variable used within them changes (Session, Meteor.user, Collections, etc.).

Give something like this a try:

```js
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(function() {
    if (MyCollection.findOne()) {
      do_some_rand_function();
    }
  });
});
```

Also note that template autoruns are automatically stopped when the template is destroyed.